# Rootkit scanning

Tags: linux, security, anti-virus, malware, rootkit

Are there any good services or ways to scan for rootkits and backdoors?

I know there are rkhunter and chkrootkit but are they even ideal anymore? They never seem updated and look more like they were good in the early 2000's

Comment: Might be worth popping over to SuperUser as opposed to ServerFault.

Comment: The rkhunter data (signatures) file was last updated this morning.  The rkhunter engine was last updated in April.  I wouldn't call that out of date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how often OSSEC updates their rootkit detection but I know it has the capability built in. Below is the link that shows the various checks that are performed - http://www.ossec.net/doc/manual/rootcheck/index.html. Overall I love the product due to it being able to do rootkit checking, integrity checking, and still being a HIDS/HIPS. You can also easily create your own rules to alert on basically anything.

Edit: As far as backdoors go, you can use the process monitoring feature - http://www.ossec.net/doc/manual/monitoring/process-monitoring.html. There is an example on the page that will alert you if the output of a netstat command changes. So if your server is fairly consistent on what ports should be open, this could definitely be a red flag.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tenable.com/products/nessus

nessus is free for personal use I think. this is up to date.

Comment: That's more of an external vulnerability scanner. Most rootkits periodically check for updates from Command and Control instead of opening a listening port now.

Comment: what you said is true, though nessus does find things that rootkits tend to modify and indirectly can discover problems related to rk attacks.